# Numbering a ListView

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a ListView whose Data Context is an ObservableCollection. I then used XAML to format the items and bind to their properties in the ListView in ListView.ItemTemplate.DataTemplate . Now, I want to add a TextBlock here to display the position of the item in the ListView through Binding in XAML. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, you just need to add a TextBlock in each item DataTemplate with the index number inside the ListView, right?

If so, you can easily do that by doing something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <!--All your various UI elements here...-->

        <!--Add a TextBlock with the formatting you want-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And in C#, add something like this after you've created your Source ObservableCollection, before assigning it to the Property inside your ViewModel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)
{
    myCollection[i].Position = Convert.ToString(i);
}
//And then, the usual
Source = myCollection
```

NB: I'm assuming you have a Property called Source in your ViewModel with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. You will also have to modify the class you use inside your ObservableCollection and add the Position property of course :)

Comment: Although I was looking for an answer which did this without using a property, this implementation will work too. Thanks!

Comment: That's the easiest way that came to my mind, I'm not sure if it's possible to do that entirely with XAML. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if you solved your problem! :)